# How to remove particular text from paragraph?

Tags: apex, string

I have rich text field . I want remove font weight style from that.

Eg:

```
"<p>Salesforce Technoligy</p><br><p><b>Releases:</b></p><ul><li><b style="font-weight: 32px;">Please stay tuned</b></li></ul><ul><li><b style="font-size: 12px;font-weight: 22px;">Click here</b></li></ul>"
```

I want remove all the font weight tags like below in apex

```
"<p>Salesforce Technoligy</p><br><p><b>Releases:</b></p><ul><li>b>Please stay tuned</b></li></ul><ul><li><b style="font-size: 12px">Click here</b>/li></ul>"
```

I have tried

```
String removetag = '<p>Salesforce Technoligy</p><br><p><b>Releases:</b></p>ul><li><b style="font-weight: 32px;">Please stay tuned</b></li></ul><ul>li><b style="font-size: 12px;font-weight: 22px;">Click here</b></li>/ul>'
removetag = removetag.remove(removetag.subStringBetween('font-weight:','"'));
removetag = removetag.replaceAll('font-weight:','');
```

My font weight will be changed dynamically
But style is empty. Anyone can help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the replace function.

```
String removetag = '<p>Salesforce Technoligy</p><br><p><b>Releases:</b></p>ul><li><b style="font-weight: 32px;">Please stay tuned</b></li></ul><ul>li><b style="font-size: 12px;font-weight: 22px;">Click here</b></li>/ul>';
removetag = removetag.replaceAll('font-weight: \\d*px;', '').remove('style=""');
```

Comment: my font weight is dynamic

Comment: i've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! It worked